# What is the advantages/disadvantages of using fputcsv?

Tags: php, fwrite, fputcsv

Below code is from the documentation of fputcsv:

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "time is: $time";
?> 

time is: 0.0037028789520264
time is: 0.0036959648132324
time is: 0.0037329196929932
```

why not just use something like the below code? they seemed like they have the same speed? In this way, you control what kind of new line you need to use like `\n` or `\r\n`

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fwrite($fp, implode(',', $fields) . "\n");
}

fclose($fp);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "time is: $time";
?> 

time is: 0.0037031173706055
time is: 0.0037119388580322
time is: 0.0036849975585938
```

> DISCLAIMER: I dont know if im using too small number of fields to
>   benchmark

Comment: The below code does not escape values to create valid csv. Just imagine a fields contains for example a comma (`,`) inside its value. Same with quote chars.

Comment: so fputcsv was made to escape properly the data to be put on CSV?

Comment: not only are you using too small a number of records, you also don't benchmark it right - you just want to benchmark the writing part (the loop itself). Try again with 10k+ records, preferably with live data so you can assert the need for proper escaping as @arkascha suggested. As a general rule reinventing the wheel is never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. you guys shed some light to me. I was in too deep of thinking CSV is just a normal text file(in nature yes but the purpose no).

Comment: Have a read of [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) that describes the structure of a CSV file, then compare that with what your homebrew version is actually doing if your array contains strings like `A, B and C` or `John O'Brien` or `Thomas "The Hitman" Hearns` or even a string containing line breaks.... fputcsv() handles all those correctly

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, thank you will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fputcsv is a helper function. Yes you can do it manualy. Under the hood there would probably be some simmelair funtionality. But it is eassier to implement this way and improves readability. You can just throw in the array and don't have to worry about escaping and so on.